# Fonts broken in Libre/Open Office Math

Tags: windows-8.1, openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-math

Can't enter any complex formula like sigma summation:

[image]

How to fix?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry Windows 8.1 prof

Comment: Under the Format tab, there's a "fonts" entry. Does it reflect fonts you have available? Alternatively, have you loaded the Liberation fonts (the defaults) from the same source you downloaded LibreOffice?